# Html.AntiForgeryToken() throws error "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a self-made project and i am getting the error mentioned above. I created 2 roles that i give to the users during registration. These 2 roles gives privileges to the users to interact with certain parts of my webpage.

"User" role would give access to ~/Jobs/Jobs and "HR" role would give access to ~/Profile/Profiles. In my page layout view that responsibles for the navigation bar it works perfectly fine. I only see the specific button on my navbar when i have the required role to see it.

Before i created these roles i just used a `!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated()` condition that redirected the user to the login page if the user is not logged in. This condition is was the starting condition of my role-specific .cshtml files.

```
         @{
              if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated())
              {
                  Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
              }
          }
          ...
```

It was working fine.

Now i have my roles and i changed it to `!User.Identity.IsInRole(string parameter)` condition that would redirect the user to the home page but i get the error mentioned above. Now this condition is the starting condition of my role-specific .cshtml files.

```
         @{
              if (!User.IsInRole("User")) // or "HR" on the other page
              {
                  Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index/");
              }
          }
          ...
```

My error is popping up in my _LoginPartial.cshtml file.

```
         @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
         @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
         {
             using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 
             "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
         {

         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         ...
```

I am getting the error when i'm trying to reach a role-specific page that i'm not allowed to reach. For example trying to reach a "HR" role-required page (~/Profile/Profiles) as a "User" throws me the error and vice versa. I'd like to be redirected instead of this error.

So i have 2 questions. Why do i get the error with the `User.IsInRole(string parameter)` condition and what does `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` do? I'd like to understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Instead of trying to handle this in the view i handled it in my controller. Although i still don't understand why it caused problem(s) in my view.